# Trying to emit socketio message in Django Rest Framwork view sometimes fails

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, socket.io, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

There are certain cases, where my Django Rest Framework application needs to send a notification using socketio to another server. Function for emitting the notification is included in the views.py file, and it's called directly from the Rest request handlers when needed.

Most of the time it works fine, however sometimes call to emit() throws an exception. So far at least three different exceptions have occurred.

The application is run on Elastic Beanstalk.

Code for emitting the message:

```
def send_request(message):
    sio = socketio.Client()

    @sio.event
    def connect():
        sio.emit(settings.KEY, message) # Exception happens on this line, if it happens at all
        sio.wait()
        sio.disconnect()

    sio.connect(settings.URL,transports='websocket')
```

Logs from three different errors below:

```
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:44.732110 2020] [:error] [pid 1713] Exception in thread Thread-262167:
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:44.732131 2020] [:error] [pid 1713] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:44.732133 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:44.732136 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     self.run()
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:44.732138 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:44.732141 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:44.732143 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/engineio/client.py", line 665, in _write_loop
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:44.732145 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     self.ws.send(encoded_packet)
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:44.732148 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 253, in send
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:44.732150 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     return self.send_frame(frame)
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:44.732152 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 278, in send_frame
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:44.732154 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     l = self._send(data)
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:44.732156 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 448, in _send
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:44.732159 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     return send(self.sock, data)
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:44.732161 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_socket.py", line 157, in send
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:44.732163 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     return _send()
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:44.732166 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_socket.py", line 139, in _send
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:44.732168 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     return sock.send(data)
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:44.732170 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 946, in send
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:44.732172 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     return socket.send(self, data, flags)
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:44.732174 2020] [:error] [pid 1713] OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.556780 2020] [:error] [pid 1713] Exception in thread Thread-257085:
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557014 2020] [:error] [pid 1713] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557030 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557037 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     self.run()
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557040 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557044 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557047 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/engineio/client.py", line 665, in _write_loop
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557063 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     self.ws.send(encoded_packet)
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557066 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 253, in send
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557068 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     return self.send_frame(frame)
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557070 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 278, in send_frame
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557072 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     l = self._send(data)
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557074 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 448, in _send
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557076 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     return send(self.sock, data)
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557078 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_socket.py", line 157, in send
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557081 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     return _send()
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557083 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_socket.py", line 139, in _send
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557085 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     return sock.send(data)
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557087 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 944, in send
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557089 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     return self._sslobj.write(data)
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557091 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 642, in write
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557093 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     return self._sslobj.write(data)
[Sun Feb 09 15:36:36.557095 2020] [:error] [pid 1713] BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818718 2020] [:error] [pid 1713] Exception in thread Thread-252469:
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818740 2020] [:error] [pid 1713] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818743 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818746 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     self.run()
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818749 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818751 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818754 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/engineio/client.py", line 665, in _write_loop
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818756 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     self.ws.send(encoded_packet)
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818759 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 253, in send
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818761 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     return self.send_frame(frame)
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818763 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 278, in send_frame
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818765 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     l = self._send(data)
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818767 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 448, in _send
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818769 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     return send(self.sock, data)
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818771 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_socket.py", line 157, in send
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818782 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     return _send()
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818785 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_socket.py", line 139, in _send
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818787 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     return sock.send(data)
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818789 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 944, in send
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818791 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     return self._sslobj.write(data)
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818793 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 642, in write
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818795 2020] [:error] [pid 1713]     return self._sslobj.write(data)
[Thu Feb 06 17:52:28.818797 2020] [:error] [pid 1713] OSError: [Errno 14] Bad address
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, this might just be intermittent failures that sometimes just occur, especially at higher traffic. Looking at the exceptions you added in your post, the messages indicate that the connection to the other end of the socket suddenly got disconnected, possibly by your end of the network skipping a beat connection to the outside.

As a possible solution, I would simply catch the `OSError` and retry sending, potentially with a small back-off to not immediately run into the same issue.